# Calculate autocorrelation in panel data?

Tags: r

I have a large panel data set in the form:

```
ID | Time| X-VALUE
---| ----|-----
1  | 1   |x
1  | 2   |x
1  | 3   |x
2  | 1   |x
2  | 2   |x
2  | 3   |x
3  | 1   |x
3  | 2   |x
3  | 3   |x
.  | .   |.
.  | .   |.
```

More specifically, I have dataset of a large set of individual stock returns over a period of 30 years. I would like to calculate the "stock-specific" first (lag 1) autocorrelation in returns for all stocks individually.

I suspect that by applying the code: `acf(pdata$return, lag.max = 1, plot = FALSE)` I'll only get som kind of "average" autocorrelation value, is that correct?

Thank you

Comment: No, you get the value at lag 1.

Comment: Yes but how do I get it for each entity (stock) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can split the data frame and do the `acf` on each subset. There are tons of ways to do this in R. For example

```
by(pdata$return, pdata$ID, function(i) { acf(i, lag.max = 1, plot = FALSE) })
```

You may need to change variable and data frame names to match your own data.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what was requested, but a real autocorrelation function for panel data in R is `collapse::psacf`, it works by first standardizing data in each group, and then computing the autocovariance on the group-standardized panel-series using proper panel-lagging. Implementation is in C++ and very fast.